# get Dialog Properties of bound ViewModel

Tags: wpf, popup, window

for my app, I've created a popup- `<Window>` that is bound to a ViewModel.

The view model of the popup:

```
public class GeneratorSelectionViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Window mWindow;

    public ICommand SelectedCommand { get; set; }
    public GeneratorListItem SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public GeneratorSelectionViewModel(Window window)
    {
        mWindow = window;
        SelectedCommand = new RelayCommand(GeneratorSelected);
    }
    private void GeneratorSelected(object parameter)
    {
        if (SelectedItem != null)
        {
            mWindow.DialogResult = true;
        }
    }
}
```

...that is bound to this popupwindow (here the codebehind):

```
public partial class GeneratorSelectionPopup : Window
{
    public GeneratorSelectionPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new GeneratorSelectionViewModel(this);
    }
}
```

In that window, I have a listbox, where SelectedItem is bound to SelectedItem-property of the VM.

I call this Popup the following way:

```
        GeneratorSelectionPopup SelectionPopup = new GeneratorSelectionPopup();
        SelectionPopup.ShowDialog();
```

Now my question...
How can I transfer that public property `SelectedItem` from the popups viewmodel to the MainWindow?

```
`SelectionPopup.SelectedItems` isn't available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `DataContext` of the window:

```
GeneratorSelectionPopup SelectionPopup = new GeneratorSelectionPopup();
SelectionPopup.ShowDialog();
var selectedItem = (SelectionPopup.DataContext as GeneratorSelectionViewModel).SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an event handler

```
public partial class GeneratorSelectionPopup : Window
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> ButtonOkClicked;

    public GeneratorSelectionViewModel ViewModel;

    public GeneratorSelectionPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new GeneratorSelectionViewModel(this);
        this.DataContext = ViewModel
    }

   private void HandleOkButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonOkClicked?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs
        {
            SelectedItem = this.ViewModel.SelectedItem
        });

        Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
    }
} 


public class MyEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public GeneratorListItem SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

And in the mainwindow cs:

```
   GeneratorSelectionPopup SelectionPopup = new GeneratorSelectionPopup();
    SelectionPopup.ButtonOkClicked += OnButtonOkClicked;
    SelectionPopup.ShowDialog();

private void OnButtonOkClicked(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: I don't want to get the property from the codebehind to the viewmodel. The viewmodel already has it's value. The solution is marked above. Thanks.